# SOS - Print values from one class to another

Tags: python, multithreading, class, dynamic, while-loop

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QApplication,QLCDNumber, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QObject, QRunnable, QThread, QThreadPool, pyqtSignal)
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import time

class Scoreboard(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        scoreLcd = QLCDNumber(self)
        scoreLcd.display(x) #How to grab values in x below to display here

        self.setGeometry(10, 50, 100, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('TIMER')
        self.show()

class CountUp(QThread):
    def run(self):  
        x = 0 
        while 1:
            x = x + 1
            time.sleep(1)
            print (x) #I want the value in x to be printed in the GUI above


def Counter():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Scoreboard()

    thread = CountUp()
    thread.finished.connect(app.exit)
    thread.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Counter()
```

I have 2 different classes CountUp which runs a while loop and Scoreboard which displays numbers. Now I'm trying to print the values in x from the CountUp class to the Scoreboard class as such:

```
scoreLcd.display(x)
```

which give me an error that x is not defined. This is cause I'm trying to get values from another class altogether.

So now the question is how to i access the values of x from the class Scoreboard

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just as the picture,you can make a native variable in the parent class

> 1.define a function that can return the value,just the set_value in X
>
> 2.define a class that includes the class X,such as Y
>
> 3.cause the X is parent of Y,so now we can directly use the X's function

Comment: Errrr,its simple.U just need 2 replace self.x with arduinoData,then use it in your chid class.Cause there's no pyQT in my pc,so just do it yourself

Comment: right,maybe a version problem,I use python2.7 and the prog runs OK

Comment: I remember the super is differ between 2.7 and 3.6,